# NSDocument isDocumentEdited and undo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a document-based application, for every user action I add an entry in the UndoManager, including selection, meaning that an 'undo' will restore the previous selection.

Some times a user will open a document, view some items by selecting them and then close the document, but even if the user didn't 'alter' anything, the user is asked to save changes, this is annoying and can be misleading to the user.

It seems that the document's dirty flag (isDocumentEdited) is automatically set when registering undo actions, but is there a way I can prevent this for some particualr undoable actions, such as selection change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `-setActionIsDiscardable:YES` on the undoManager when you register actions that don’t need to be saved.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this in my original question, but one of the requirements is that is has to run on Snow Leopard, so -setActionIsDiscardable: is out of my options, since its available on v10.7. My bad!!!